# Label width in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, width, label, frame

I'm writing an app with tkinter and I am trying to put several labels in a frame... Unfortunately,

```
windowTitle=Label(... width=100)
```

and

```
windowFrame=Frame(... width=100)
```

are very different widths...

So far, I use this code:

```
windowFrame=Frame(root,borderwidth=3,relief=SOLID,width=xres/2,height=yres/2)
windowFrame.place(x=xres/2-160,y=yres/2-80)
windowTitle=Label(windowFrame,background="#ffa0a0",text=title)
windowTitle.place(x=0,y=0)
windowContent=Label(windowFrame,text=content,justify="left")
windowContent.place(x=8,y=32)

...

#xres is screen width
#yres is screen height
```

For some reason, setting label width doesn't set width correctly, or doesn't use pixels as measurement units... So, is there a way to place `windowTitle` widget in such way that it adapts to the lenght of the frame, or to set label width in pixels?

Comment: Why in the world are you using the Place geometry manager? Use Pack or Grid.

Comment: It's generally not necessary to specify the width of a label. Pack it into the frame, let the geometry manager handle it. Resize the frame.

Comment: I really need frame to be set to specific location and to have specific size... Is it possible to use `w.pack()` method to resize widgets inside the frame?

Comment: You're putting a frame at an explicit size/location, and inside this frame you are putting a label an an explicit size/location? (Are you sure you need to do it that way?)

Comment: Hmm. The placer should let you specify the absolute width of your label widget. When you say "setting label width doesn't set width correctly", are you telling the label what width to be, or are you telling the placer what width to place the label at?

Comment: Well, I could use `windowTitle.pack()` if it didn't resize the frame

Comment: I was trying to set width in `windowTitle.Label(...), but that was a failure... It would either be placed over the frame border, or there would be an empty part between right frame border and title widget

Comment: No, When I said "Use pack or grid", that was a general statement, not "that's why this isn't working". How are you specifying the width of the label, though? I don't see that in your code and it is significant.

Comment: I used to have `windowTitle=Label(windowFrame,background="#ffa0a0",text=title,width=int(xres/14.2))`

Comment: Try `WindowContent.place(...,width=int(...))` ? Also, for windowTitle.pack() resizing the frame you're packing the windowTitle label into, there's a way to tell geometry management not to propagate up, but I don't rememeber what it is...

Comment: Hmm. In tcl, it would be `[pack propage $frame 0]`. Not sure how to translate that to TkInter, but it might be what you need.

Comment: If you are talking about `pack_propagate(0)`, that's no good. It wouldn't shrink my frame, but I'd still be having the same problem... And I can't see the difference between your code and mine...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`height` and `width` define the size of the label in **text units** when it contains text.
Follow @Elchonon Edelson's advice and set size of frame + one small trick:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def make_label(master, x, y, h, w, *args, **kwargs):
    f = Frame(master, height=h, width=w)
    f.pack_propagate(0) # don't shrink
    f.place(x=x, y=y)
    label = Label(f, *args, **kwargs)
    label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    return label

make_label(root, 10, 10, 10, 40, text='xxx', background='red')
make_label(root, 30, 40, 10, 30, text='xxx', background='blue')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not, really what I had in mind... However, `fill=X` should serve me nicely... Thanks...