# TKinter grid layout shows expected behavior only with label image

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a grid of pictures and comments like a detail view in a folder. However, when I don't load the image (the "magic two lines" after *XXX*), the layout collapses and I see only the borders, not even `Label` widgets. But of course it should work in both cases. Here is some simplified version:

```py
import os.path as osp
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

IMG_FILE = '/your/magic/image/path/name.png'

class Comparator:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('1350x730+0+0')
        self.ctrl = ctrl = tk.Frame(self.root, padx=10, pady=10)
        ctrl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lframe = tk.Frame(self.root)
        lframe.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2)

        inner_frame = tk.Frame(lframe, bg='#444', padx=7, pady=7)
        inner_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # group of widgets
        tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(IMG_FILE))
        for num in range(23):
            yard = tk.Frame(inner_frame, bg='#222', padx=6, pady=6)
            ya_col = num % 4
            ya_row = num // 4
            yard.grid(column = ya_col, row = ya_row)

            stone = tk.Label(yard, text='Img name', width=179, height=179)
            stone.grid(row=0, column=0)
            # XXX magic two lines that generate the right layout:
            stone.image = tk_img
            stone.config(image=stone.image)
            # end magic two lines
            tk.Label(yard, text='%d : %d %d' % (num, ya_row, ya_col)).grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.root.mainloop()

Comparator()
```

There are a few redundant `tk.Frame` instances because it's just a simplified version; for instance `ctrl`  is supposed to be filled with a lot of buttons etc. Actually, I also wanted the  `inner_frame` to be in a scrollable `tk.Canvas`, but let's say that's another story...

I don't understand what happens. Any suggestions would be very nice :-)

[edit] Maybe it depends on the fact that width is interpreted either in pixels or in number of chars? How do I fix that?

Comment: `tkinter.Label`'s width and height are in characters not pixels. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363832/11106801)

Comment: Well not exactly. They in fact become pixels if you define an `config(image=)`  and that is the problem ! _Edit_ So what I did is to fit in an dummy image...